# Apache alias to Ruby on Rails application

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, httpd.conf, alias

I have a RoR application that runs in `/var/rails/redmine`, and would like it to appear as a subdirectory in my Apache server (primarily so I can use a SSL certificate and not muck around with subdomains).

My httpd.conf currently has a `<VirtualHost>` directive with the DocumentRoot set to the Redmine install; this works fine when I use redmine.www2.domain.com as the url. I'd like to be able to use www2.domain.com/redmine, but am unable to get the alias to work.

I've tried adding an `Alias /redmine /var/rails/redmine/public` line to the config in a few places, but so far it only gives me errors (usually cannot access directory) when I go to the path. I've seen a few references to having to set some other paths for mod_passenger, but I'm unable to find information on how that works exactly.

Is there a way to give the RoR app an alias and have it appear to be in a subdirectory, or should I actually move it there, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use some connector like `mod_ruby`, `cgi` or `fcgi` to access your rails application.

See this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Configure%20Apache) for further documentation (Based on ubuntu linux)

Comment: Stage one went smooooothly. Thanks for the guide (and +2 for the avvy ;).

Comment: Is `thin` a connector?